# Inserting blob objects in Yii without using forms

Tags: php, yii, blob

I need a way to insert images into a PostgreSQL database without using forms. I have a folder that contains a set of images named say aa.jpg, bb.jpg .... zz.jpg. I also have a table that contains the names aa,bb...zz as individual records.

Now my question is how do I insert these images into the DB without manually using forms. There are loads of [Yii tutorials](http://yiichina.net/wiki/95/saving-files-to-a-blob-field-in-the-database/) to do the manual insertion, but none explaining how to do it programmatically.

Basically I need a way to use lo_import function in Yii. The thing is, image is a column in the table whose type is OID and my insertion code in Yii is as follows

```
update('table_name', array(
                'image' => "lo_import('$image_path')",
                    ), 'column=:name', array(':name' => $name));
```

on executing this, it gives me the following error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type oid:

Solution: Ok, so following @Uday's answer, I just used the function in Yii to execute sql statements directly.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($Update_sql_command)->query();
```

I am all ears if there is a better way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need Yii for that? write a function to iterate through all images use `get_file_contents()` to get contents and store it to mysql.

```
$imgContents = get_file_contents('file.Name') ;
$sql = 'insert into table_name (blob_column) values("'. $imgContents.'")';
```

Comment: I got that part, I am just trying to find out if there is anyway I can do this in Yii. PS: I have edited my question a little.

Comment: OK, I have marked yours as the right answer for now because it atleast lead me to the answer. But I dont know if this solution what you meantioned is the correct one. Thanks anyways!